# Parse iTunes API (which uses JSON) w/ PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, itunes

This is the first time I have came in contact with JSON, and I literally have no idea how to parse it with PHP. I know that functions to decode JSON exist in PHP, but I am unsure how to retrieve specific values defined in the JSON. Here's the JSON for my app:

http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=enoda&entity=software

I require a few values to be retrieved, including the App Icon (artworkUrl100), Price (price) and Version (version).

The things I am having issues with is putting the URL of the App Icon into an actual HTML image tag, and simply retrieving the values defined in the JSON for the Price and Version.

Any help/solutions to this would be fantastic.

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, i have something similar, for my App review website, here is a bit code:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close')));
$content = file_get_contents("http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsLookup?id=$appid&country=de");
$content = json_decode($content);
$array = $content->results["0"];
$version = $array->version;
$artistname = $array->artistName;
$artistid = $array->artistId;
```

Thats what I used to get Information from the AppStore, maybe you can change the link and some names and it would work for you.

Comment: e.g. `echo "<img src='$icon' width='100' />";`

Comment: and how do you get the $appid for a specific app ?

Comment: the App-ID you have to enter manually.. Depending on the usage of the script you have to enter the specific App-ID in your database, or the user has to enter it if he want's the AppStore information. I don't know a way to automatically find the App ID by search queries or something.. Although this would be nice, maybe it's possible?